# Xcode complains about structure of if-statement using Swift and Xcode 6

Tags: cocoa-touch, if-statement, swift, ios8, xcode6

I was wondering what this if statement is wrong. I am using swift. What I am trying to do is to perform multiple checks from my textfields, mainly to restrict their text lenght between the ranges declared in the if statement. Here is my code:

```
if countElements(usernameTextField.text) < 16 && 
   countElements(usernameTextField.text) > 4  && 
   countElements(passwordTextField.text) > 5  && 
   countElements(passwordTextField.text) < 16 {
   //Do something
} else {
   //Do something else
}
```

The compiler complains says the following:

"Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol '_CollectionType'"

Do you guys have any idea of why this is showing up?

Thank you in advance for your advice/recommendations/explanations.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` propety in `UITextField` declared as:

```
var text: String!
```

So you should rewrite your code to:

**Option 1:**

```
if countElements(usernameTextField.text!) < 16 { ... }
```

This option is preferable since it will take into account emoji character. 
For instance if you add a flag character that counts for 4 places you will be counted as one.

**Option 2 (do not use it):**

```
if usernameTextField.text.utf16Count < 16 { ... }
```

This options counts utf16 symbols so in case of flag emoji you will have visible chars count +3. So do not go this track. I've added this just to show that it should not be used.

Comment: Choose Option 1 since Option 2 will fail for names/passwords that contain emoji.

Comment: So why option 1 need `!`? Isn't it implicitly unwrapped optional and in fact a `String`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Zaph! I was lucky to post an update about it just a bit before your comment :)

Comment: @Kirsteins, I really do not have answer for such a behavior. You are right that it should just work without `!`. However it works as if property was declared as `String?`. May be help in xCode just lies us.

Comment: I suspect that the bridging is not working correctly and the "!" forces the `NSString` to a `String`.

Comment: This really looks like a Swift bug to me. `let str : String! = "Foo" ; let c = countElements(str)` (without importing Foundation at all) already produces this error message.

Comment: @Zaph: What I meant is that `countElements()` called on an implicitly unwrapped `String` already gives a compiler error, so the problem already occurs without any bridging from `NSObject`.

Comment: @MartinR Good example, catch.

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you for your detailed response and explanation!